# Position Label under the Horizontal Bar

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Is it possible to put the Label of the Bar under it in a HorizontalBar layout?

Most of the examples I see online usually state putting the bar's label inside the bar, I haven't really seen one that places the label either on top or under the bar.

[image: Like this]

```
 yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        mirror: true,
             }
```

Here's what I've done so far

https://jsfiddle.net/knyut1db/

Answer (score 6):

My bad, I overlooked the `labelOffset` in the documentation.

```
ticks: {
   mirror: true,
   labelOffset: 50
       }
```